# Onboard audio and LAN not working

Tags: audio, network-adapter

Yesterday, I cleaned up my pc and both onboard realtek network adapter and realtek audio adapter are stopped working. (I've removed the nvidia geforce 8400gs graphic card and using onboard graphic card). I tried with Ubuntu live CD and audio (only right side of speaker) is working. Speaker is working well. I've tried with my phone. LAN doesn't work on both windows and ubuntu eventhough I can see the orange light at LAN port.

I've reset the CMOS setting by removing battery. Install drivers from driver cd came with mobo eventhough not compatible with windows 8. But it worked without any problem after first windows 8 installation. It just stopped working after I cleaned up the pc. I've also refresh windows 8 and still doesn't work.

Mobo is Asus p5kpl-am/ps.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is you use proper maintenace techinques to clean your PC, like only using compressed air cans to blow, always have an anti-static band and mat (or something to protect the equipment against current flows) and soft brushes to get the dirt off it, they're sometimes not necessary but when you work with other's people equipment you can't allow yourself to mess up. Chances are that your LAN/modem chipset became faulty. How exacty did you clean it?

Comment: I used brush and hair dryer to clean the dirt. But didn't use anti-status mat as you said but I had it power cable removed. Audio & LAN onboard devices are protected by aluminium(not sure) shell from manifacturer. May be I've damaged the power supply path on board for these devices? :(

Comment: The hair dryer is a chip killer, many people even use it to re-bail chips. It may have burnt something.

Comment: Oh. I mean hair dryer with cold air. The only choice i have is to buy sound card and network card. But these pci-e slots are close to graphic card's pci-e ports which will block the graphic card's fan. USB sound cards wont support windows 8 i think...

Comment: Oh, my bad I thought you were using warm air. Anyway, this is most certainly an issue while giving maintenance. Good luck man.